# Global variables with jQuery Widget Factory Plugin?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-plugins, widget, factory

I'm trying to create an instance from another library on `_create` and the access this from private and public functions in my widget. Is this possible?

```
$.widget('namespace.pluginName', {
    _create: function() {
        // Create instance from other library on create 
        var someovar = otherlibrary.function(options);
    },
    _privatemethod: function() {
        var self = this;
        // Call "samovar" instance?
        self._create.somevar.function( "option", function() {
            // Do sutff 
        });     
    }
}));
```

I also like to cache my selections only once like this: `var div = $('#my_div');` on `_create`. Right now I need to reselect the same div in 10 different functions. Is this the way to do it or should I just ignore the caching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested, but try to do it like this:

```
$.widget('namespace.pluginName', {
    _create: function() {
        // Create instance from other library on create 
        this.someovar = otherlibrary.function(options);
    },
    _privatemethod: function() {
        var self = this;
        // Call "samovar" instance?
        this.somevar.function( "option", function() {
            // Do sutff 
        });     
    }
}));
```

Alto $.widget() takes 3rd parameter, which is your widget prototype (another object). Maybe it can be somehow useful in your case - for example to store mentioned caches.